# Rename values based on a filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of data with three values: `Germany`, `Federal Republic Of Germany`, and `German Democratic Republic` as the values inside the column . I have another column called `Effect` that is a date class. I want to rename the `Country` value from `Germany` to `Federal Republic Of Germany` for all values where `Effect > 1990`.

I've tried the following code and it has not worked

```
clean.data$Country <- clean.data %>% filter(Country == "Germany" & Effect > 1990) %>% rename(Federal Republic Of Germany = Germany) #Method 1
clean.data$Country <- clean.data %>% filter(Country == "Germany" & Effect > 1990) %>% rename("Federal Republic Of Germany" = "Germany") #Method 2
```

I also can't seem to find the command to pull the row numbers that meet the filter. If I could, I would do

```
rownumbers <- #Command to find row numbers
clean.data$Country[rownumbers] <- "Federal Republic Of Germany"
```

What other methods are there to change the observation? Or am I doing something wrong in the above dplyr chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assignment should be to the same object or different object and not a column as the output from `rename` is still a `data.frame` and `rename` is for renaming the column and not the value

```
library(dplyr)
clean.data1 <-  clean.data %>%
   filter(Country == "Germany" & Effect > 1990) %>%
   rename(`Federal Republic Of Germany` = "Germany")
```

If we want to change the value, then do

```
clean.data %>%
   mutate(Country = case_when(Country == "Germany" & Effect > 1990 ~ "Federal Republic Of Germany", TRUE ~ Country))
```

---

In `base R`, we can use an index if we need to change the values of the 'Country' column

```
i1 <- with(clean.data, Country == "Germany" & Effect > 1990)
clean.data$Country[i1] <- "Federal Republic Of Germany"
```

Comment: So it looks like I used `rename` wrong and should have used `mutate`. For future reference, what do`~ "Federal Republic Of Germany", TRUE ~ Country)` and `case_when()` do?

Comment: @checkmate363 Yes, `rename` is renaming the column name.  The `~` is an operator to suggest that if the logical expression on the lhs of that operator is TRUE, then the rhs is the value.  the `TRUE` at the end will be for all other cases, return the `Country` column

Comment: Okay thank you. I've got one more follow up. I'm now trying to rename `Germany` to `Weimar Republic` for `Effect < 1945`. I used your same code again, but changed `"Federal Republic Of Germany"` to `"Weimar Republic"` and changed `Effect > 1990` to `Effect < 1945`. However, I am getting Effect dates ranging from 1929-1986. Do I need to change something else?

Comment: @checkmate363 is your `Effect` column numeric class i.e. `class(clean.data$Effect)`

Comment: @checkmate363 can you also check if there are NA elements in those columns as `==` returns NA for cases that are NA

Comment: It is a date class, and yes, there are some NAs.

Comment: @checkmate363 If it is a `Date` class you cannot do the `Effect > 1990` you need to extract the 'year' from the `Date` i.e. if you have lubridate `year(Effect)  < 1945` or in `base R` `as.numeric(format(Effect, "%Y")) < 1945`

Comment: I do have lubridate, so that sounds good. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R` this can work:

```
#Code
rownumbers <- which(clean.data$Country == "Germany" & clean.data$Effect > 1990)
clean.data$Country[rownumbers] <- "Federal Republic Of Germany"
```